# Detecting URLs among Paths

Tags: objective-c, nsurl

How to detect if it is a Web URL or a path?

in NSUrl Apple reference page has written, it accept a URL if it is based on standard, but any kind of string it accept as a URL, like this code:

```
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"/book.xml"];

    NSLog(@"%@",url);
```

This is not a web URL but it hold it and also return it as its value.
I have tried this function, it works but not for all the URLs!

```
-(BOOL) urlIsValiad: (NSString *) url {

    NSString *regex = @"((?:http|https)://(?:www\\.)?[\\w\\d\\-_]+\\.\\w{2,3}/?(?:[\\w\\d\\-./_]+)?)";

    NSPredicate *regextest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", regex];

    if ([regextest evaluateWithObject: url] == YES) {
        NSLog(@"It is a valid URL!");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"It is not valid URL!");
    }


    return [regextest evaluateWithObject:url];

}
```

My concern is detecting URLs among other paths!

Answer (score 0):

you want to look at data detectors:

https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSDataDetector_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: i have edited my post, i used someething similar but even it has some exceptional cases that does not work.!!

Comment: are you sure NSDataDetector doesn't work? i may have misunderstood, but NSDataDetector should be able to find multiple URLs in one long string.

Comment: unfortunately i cant use that! because i am going to provide an application which works on OSX versions from 10.5!

Answer (score 0):

How about [`NSDataDetector`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSDataDetector_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
NSString *string = @"This is a sample of a http://abc.com/efg.php?EFAei687e3EsA sentence with a URL within it.";
NSDataDetector *linkDetector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypeLink error:nil];
NSArray *matches = [linkDetector matchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];

for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches)
{
  if ([match resultType] == NSTextCheckingTypeLink) 
  {
    NSURL *url = [match URL];
    NSLog(@"found URL: %@", url);
  }
}
```

This way you don't have to rely on an unreliable regular expression, and as Apple upgrades their link detection code, you get those improvements for free.

Comment: unfortunately i cant use that! because i am going to provide an application which works  from 10.5!

Comment: ahh, sorry, didn't realise that!